# libxml: How to add sibling nodes to root node

Tags: xml, libxml2

I'm implementing a function doing xml signature with libxml.
How could I add sibling nodes to root node?

original xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object>
...
</object>
```

what I want:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object>
...
</object>
<additional node>
...
</additional node>
```

After parsing, the object node will be the root node, so I can't use xmlNewChild.
What function should I use to achieve what I want.

Thank you.

Comment: As that is not a well formed XML document (a document can only have one root node) , I'd not expect that to be supported.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. But this might happen when signing the whole xml file with detached signature.

Comment: You were right. There's a tricky way to add sibling nodes to root node, but the result xml file can't be parse correctly with libxml.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Libxml is supposed to produce valid xml files, that is having only one root node.

Padawan, if you know a tricky way to do that, please post another answer and accept it yourself.